# Django development server quits itself when accessing admin page

Tags: django, admin, web-development-server

I am following the django docs tutorial to build a polls app i just created the superuser but whenever i try to access the admin page the server quits on its own with no error message that's in both chrome and firefox i'm on windows

Comment: That's because the code runs on the server (which is your machine| Django terminal in pure English), The error logs will be in the Django terminal, Kindly edit the question & include them then reply me so that I can help

Comment: like i said the server exits without any error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check your version numbers of Django and Python to ensure compatibility. [There is a problem with Django 3.0 (the latest version) and with version 3.7.0 of Python](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31067) and potentially its older versions as well.

Try updating your Python installation to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: thanks a tonne you solved my frustration!!!. After I had to reconfigure and reinstall all my required packages for the app lol .